# bind (readline) doesn't update bash prompt

Tags: bash, shell, readline

I've set-up a hot-key (Meta-leftArrow) to switch between directories, here's my code:

```
bind -x '"\e\M-[D": "cd -"'
```

This works but, it doesn't update the bash prompt to reflect the current directory, the behavior looks like:

```
[fbynite ~]$ cd /usr/src
[fbynite /usr/src]$ #press hot-key (M-leftArrow)
/home/fbynite
[fbynite /usr/src]$ pwd
/home/fbynite
[fbynite ~]$
```

The prompt is only correctly updated after I enter another command, how do I get the prompt to update after pressing my hot-key?

I'm using bash version 4.4.19 and readline version 7.0.3_1

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @Barmar, just because you don't know the answer doesn't make it a non-programming question. I'm trying to learn how to programmatically update the bash prompt. There's a number of other questions/answers on SO in similarity and they aren't being closed.

Comment: Configuring an application is not the same as programming. You don't need to write any scripts to set the `bash` prompt, you just set the `PS1` variable in `.profile`.

Comment: What is your `PS1` setting?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Barmar, the setting of `PS1` is not the issue here. The problem is the way `bind -x` executes a shell-command and ignores updating the `PS1` variable - my provided example is re-producible.

Comment: Why would you be updating the `PS1` variable? If you want the current working directory to be shown in the prompt, you put `\w` in `PS1`. There's no need to update it after each command.

Comment: @Barmar, that's what I'm saying - `bind -x` isn't updating `PS1` after executing `cd -`; the information in `PS1` becomes stale. After `cd -` executes, the working directory changes but `PS1` still shows I'm in the previous working directory even though I'm not. If I press the return key (or any other command) after invoking my hot-key, the prompt is correctly displayed. It's weird.

Comment: `bind -x` isn't supposed to update `PS1`. The shell automatically replaces `\w` with the working directory every time it displays the prompt. This just sounds like some kind of `bash` bug to me.

Comment: I've reproduced this, and I think I see what's going on. It's not actually displaying a new prompt, it's just re-displaying the last prompt. Put `\t` in your prompt and you'll see that it keeps displaying the same time every time you use your keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Report this to `bug-bash@gnu.org`

Comment: @Barmar, ahhh, I see - thanks for the insight, much appreciated!